# FXM - Rendering not shown on external site

Tags: fxm

I have configured an external site in FXM and added a view rendering.

[image]

The highlighted part is the text from the rendering. Published the rendering and this change also.
But on the external site, this is displayed the same way, i.e without JS/CSS.

[image]

The rendering is a carousel. The related JS/CSS are in the external site.
In the Sitecore instance, I have only its markup and static images.
Should the Sitecore instance also have the JS/CSS?

What am i missing?

Comment: did you publish the fxm page? if you have workflow, make sure it is in approved state

Comment: @SitecorePro I have updated my question. pls check.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do. are you putting a sitecore component in external side using place holders? if it is a sitecore component, it will have its assets in sitecore. As far as the external site is concerns it will display the actual site without the need for assets.

Comment: @SitecorePro. I would like to render a carousel on the ext. site. The js & css needed for that are available in the ext. site. From sitecore, it is a plain view rendering with image paths. The component is rendered on the ext.site but it is not showing as expected. The css/js are not being applied.